# How do I compare the words in the DS's and print the translation?

Tags: c, data-structures, google-translate, doubly-linked-list

I'm making a translation program in c to output raw word translations from English to Spanish. I've managed to break down the input string and store the words separately in a linked list, I also split the translation combo separated by commas in a text file, and stored that in a structure. Now my issue is, how do I compare both and print the translation result effectively? The last attempt I tried is in the code below which did not yield any results. The program should compare the English to the Spanish words, find a match in the dictionary, and print the Spanish translation without grammatical considerations. Thanks in advance.[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Gp1.jpg)
Format of my dictionary: one, uno

[Dictionary format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcoKa.jpg)

```
/*Project- English to Spanish Translator*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
// ----------User Definitions---------------//
#define MAX_SIZE 1000

//------------Data Structure--------------//
// Implementation of a Doubly Linked List
struct Dictionary
{
    char word[50];
    struct Dictionary *prev; 
    struct Dictionary *next; 

} * head; // points to the first node in the link list

// Structure to store file values
typedef struct F_Dict
{
    char engword[50];
    char esword[50];
} * dict;

// ----------Function Prototypes----------//
void get_word(char arr[]);
void insert_word(char *word);
void displayAll();
void translate(struct Dictionary *node, FILE *fp);

int main()
{
    //-------------File Operations-------------------//
    FILE *dict;
    dict = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    //-----------Global Variables-----------------------//
    head = NULL;
    char input[MAX_SIZE];

    //--------------User Input-----------------------//
    printf("\nPlease enter a sentence in English: ");
    fgets(input, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

    get_word(input);
    translate(head, dict);
    // displayAll();

    fclose(dict);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//----------Function Definitions----------//
void get_word(char arr[])
{
    char new_str[20][20];
    int i, j = 0, ctr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(arr); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == ' ' || arr[i] == '\0') // If Space or NULL is found assign it to new_str[ctr]
        {
            new_str[ctr][j] = '\0';
            ctr++;
            j = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            new_str[ctr][j] = arr[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= ctr; i++)
        insert_word(new_str[i]);
}

void insert_word(char *word)
{
    struct Dictionary **head_ref = &head; 

    struct Dictionary *dict = (struct Dictionary *)malloc(sizeof(struct Dictionary)); // Allocate node

    strcpy(dict->word, word); // Insert Data

    dict->next = (*head_ref); 

    dict->prev = NULL; 

    dict->next = (*head_ref); 

    if ((*head_ref) != NULL) 
    {
        (*head_ref)->prev = dict;
    }
    // Move the head to point to the new node
    (*head_ref) = dict;
}

void displayAll()
{
    struct Dictionary **head_ref = &head;
    struct Dictionary *last = *head_ref; // Intialising the last node to be equal to the first node when list is empty
    // Moving from start to end of the linked list
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        last = head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    // moves backward through all the nodes of the linked list and displays all information
    while (last != *head_ref)
    {

        printf("Words: %s\n", last->word);

        last = last->prev;
    }
    system("pause");
}

void translate(struct Dictionary *node, FILE *fp)
{
    struct Dictionary **head_ref = &node;
    struct Dictionary *last = *head_ref; // Intialising the last node to be equal to the first node when list is empty
    // Moving from start to end of the linked list
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        last = node;
        node = node->next;
    }
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf("File Error!");
    }

    char buff[1024]; // Store the first 1024 lines into the buffer
    int row_count = 0;
    int line_count = 0;

    dict values[999]; // struct array to store values

    int i = 0;
    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp) && last != *head_ref)
    {
        line_count = 0;
        row_count++;

        char *line = strtok(buff, ",");
        while (line)
        {
            if (line_count == 0)
                strcpy(values[i]->engword, line);

            if (line_count == 1)
                strcpy(values[i]->esword, line);

            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(values); j++)
            {

            
                if (strcmp(last->word, values[j]->engword) == 1)
                {
                    printf("%s", values[j]->esword);
                }
                else
                {
                    last = last->prev;
                    last++;
                }
            }
            line = strtok(NULL, ","); // update the field value
            line_count++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // printf("%s  %s", values[j].engword, values[j].esword);
}
```

Comment: Yo, I don't know where you learned to write hanging comments on every line (_e.g._ your `insert_word` function) but you should unlearn that before it becomes a habit.  Make short comments explaining generally what should happen, then write the few lines of code that does it.  Simple code is self-documenting, and a brief explanation followed by some code is far more readable.  Nobody _ever_ wants to see `prev = NULL; // set prev to NULL`.  If you have a teacher, and they insist on this style, please send them to me to receive a verbal spanking.

Comment: I do it to help myself understand the process better, I'm new to programming so it helps, I don't submit like this however lol. Thank you for the advice! @paddy

Comment: @paddy Go ahead and spank me. I teach this.

Comment: @nicomp naughty!  Stop it! :P

Comment: @SpartnLife compare two versions of your insert function [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v9svTPKb7).  That aside, and regarding your actual question _"how do I compare both and print the translation result effectively?"_ ...  are you surprised that there is still no answer after almost a day?  You have not shown your data, your program's output, nor what you expect or what kinds of things you've learned during debugging sessions.

Comment: Taking a quick look at the code, some immediate things I notice are: 1) Be aware that `fgets` leaves a newline.  If you want to test for whitespace, use `isspace` instead of checking explicit characters.  2) Be aware `strcmp` returns 0 when strings match.  3) Every time a line is processed, you're searching the entire `values` array for a word, including entries that are uninitialized or partially initialized.  4) `last++` is bogus and dangerous -- think about what that actually does.  5) Your dictionary can only contain 999 values -- you sure you don't want to store _that_ in a list instead?

Comment: 6) `sizeof(values)` is the size _in bytes_ of the array.  It is not the number of items.  You're absolutely clobbering your stack memory.

Comment: thanks a lot, @paddy. I'm making changes and improving my logic of the problem.